# JavaScript onKeyDown and Jaws Screenreader - Not working together

Tags: javascript, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I cannot get JavaScript onKeyDown for keyboard keys 1,2,3,4,5,and 6 to work with Jaws Screenreader.  Specifically, I have an html document that is automatically generated with links in it.  The links are related in different ways (e.g., a series of links related to dogs, and another set of links related to cats).  I want the user to be able to switch between the series of links they're navigating through simply by switching the key they are pressing down.  This currently works, but not for users of Jaws Screenreader.  For them, nothing happens when they press down on the keys.
Other notes: the keyDown event needs to be able to occur anywhere in the document, so it's not isolated to a small area within the document (e.g., a form or a drop-down menu).
Is there a relatively straightforward solution to allow JAWS screenreader users to press different keys to switch between modes?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Are you exiting the normal browsing mode in which 1-6 and other keys are set to jump to various elements?  For example 1-6 jump to headings.  If not, press INSERT+Space first.

I'm assuming this is an action where someone holds down 1 and then perhaps arrows through dog-related links, or holds down 2 for cat-related links?  If so, it seems to me there's probably a more usable and accessible way to implement this.  In general, there has to be a really good reason for me to want to learn your site's keyboard shortcuts, especially if I can do the task with approximately the same number of strokes with screen reader native commands.